# Способы работы со строками

Tags: javascript

Написать функцию, которая принимает двузначное число и возвращает его в текстовом виде.

Например: 35 – тридцать пять, 89 – восемьдесят девять, 12 – двенадцать.

Я сделал это так, но мне кажется, что есть решение и короче.

Потом я вспомнил про регулярные выражения, которые я никогда не учил. Хотел спросить, как, к примеру, эта задача решалась бы с помощью регулярных выражений?

```js
function textNumber(number) {
  let first = ['Один', 'Два', 'Три', 'Четыре', 'Пять', 'Шесть', 'Семь', 'Восемь', 'Девять'];
  let second = ['Десять', 'Одинадцать', 'Двенадцать', 'Тринадцать', 'Четырнадцать', 'Пятнадцать', 'Шестнадцать', 'Семьнадцать', 'Восемьнадцать', 'Девяднадцать', 'Двадвать'];
  let third = ['Двадцать', 'Тридцать', 'Сорок', 'Пятьдесят', 'Шестьдесят', 'Семьдесят', 'Восемьдесят', 'Девяносто'];
  if (number > 0 && number <= 9) {
    return first[number - 1];
  }
  if (number >= 10 && number <= 20) {
    return second[number - 10];
  }
  if (number > 20 && number <= 99) {
    let str = `${number}`;
    str = str.split('');
    let firstNumber = str[0];
    let secondNumber = str[1];
    //return [ third[firstNumber - 2], first[secondNumber - 1] ];
    return `${third[firstNumber - 2]} ${first[secondNumber - 1]}`;
  }
}
alert(textNumber(7));
alert(textNumber(20));
alert(textNumber(55));
```

Comment: Никак бы не решалась. Регулярные выражения не для этого. Проверку на >= в вашем коде можно убрать, она ничего не дает.

Comment: к сожалению, вышеприведенный код (который больше) некорректно отрабатывает 30,40,50,60 и т.п.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Хотел спросить, как, к примеру, эта задача решалась бы с помощью регулярных выражений?

Регулярные выражения применяются для проверки соответствия строки шаблону, и/или для извлечения подстрок. То есть, они для обработки ***строковых*** входных данных.
А у данной задачи, входные данные - это ***числа***, и суть заключается в их обработке... Так что, регулярки в этой задаче неприменимы (они могли бы применяться при обратном преобразовании: слов в числа).

---

> мне кажется, что есть решение и короче

Код не сократился, зато символьный объем словарика меньше))

```js
console.log(Array.from({ length: 100 }, 
  (v, i) => i + ': ' + textNumber(i)
).join('\n')); 

function textNumber(number) {
  const dict = [
    ['ноль', 'один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять', 'десять', '', 'две', '', 'четыр', 'пят', 'шест', 'сем', 'восем', 'девят'], 
    ['', '', 'двадцать', 'тридцать', 'сорок', '', '', '', '', 'девяносто']
  ]; 
  if (number >= 0 && number <= 10)
    return dict[0][number]; 
  if (number > 10 && number <= 19)
    return (dict[0][number] || dict[0][number - 10]) + 'надцать'; 
  if (number >= 20 && number <= 99) {
    const [units=0, tens] = [...('' + number)].reverse().map(Number); 
    return [
      tens ? dict[1][tens] || (dict[0][tens] + 'десят') : '', 
      units ? dict[0][units] : ''
    ].join(' '); 
  }
}
```